# When are the static constructors executed, before or after static fields?

Tags: c#, .net, static, static-constructor

Consider I have

```
public class ClassA
{
     public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

And then I use it like this

```
public class ClassD
{
     static readonly ClassA PropertyE = new ClassA();

     static ClassD()
     {
          PropertyE.PropertyB = "valueF";
     }
}
```

but the rest of the code didn't work as I expected. Then I rewrote ClassD, and it worked

```
public class ClassD
{
     static readonly ClassA PropertyE = new ClassA { PropertyB = "valueF" };
}
```

In which way are these two code samples different? I expected that they had the same behavior, but they don't.

Comment: What exactly didn't work after the first example? Maybe the cause isn't found here but rather a result of something you left behind (per @p.s.w.g's comment)

Comment: You need to expand upon _but the rest of the code didn't work as I expected_ with emphasis on what you expected (_I expected that they had the same behavior, but they don't_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645612%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> If a class contains any static fields with initializers, **those initializers are executed in textual order immediately prior to executing the static constructor**.

The only difference between your two classes is how `PropertyE` is initialized. In the first, sample, `ClassD.PropertyE` is assigned first, then `ClassA.PropertyB`. In the second sample, `ClassA.PropertyB` is assigned first, then `ClassD.PropertyE`. This *could* produce slightly different results.

You might also have issues with circular dependencies among fields. As the MSDN article states:

> It is possible to construct circular dependencies that allow static fields with variable initializers to be observed in their default value state.
>
> ```
> using System;
> class A
> {
>    public static int X;
>    static A() {
>       X = B.Y + 1;
>    }
> }
> class B
> {
>    public static int Y = A.X + 1;
>    static B() {}
>    static void Main() {
>       Console.WriteLine("X = {0}, Y = {1}", A.X, B.Y);
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> produces the output
>
> > X = 1, Y = 2

Comment: If this was the case, the two code samples would have the same behavior, wouldn't they?

Comment: @JaderDias Can you explain *how* they behave differently?

Comment: The behavior was the same as if the static constructor wasn't executed at all.

Comment: @JaderDias I tried a sample app using your code with slight modifications (`this.` not valid in static constructor, `PropertyE` made public, and `valueF` replace with a string constant `"valueF"`. I got exactly what you would expect: `Console.WriteLine(ClassD.PropertyE.PropertyB); // valueF`

Comment: @JaderDias not when it comes to the order of initialization.

Comment: I'll test it tomorrow